# Assign rows from one dataframe to another dataframe at a discretion

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to generate df_Result_Sensor automatically.

I would like the dataframe (df_Result_Sensor) to only receive df_Sensor rows where the ['TimeStamp'] Column was not contained in the df_Message ['date init'] and df_Message ['date end'] ranges.

```
    #In the code example, I wrote a df_Result_Sensor manually, just to illustrate the desired output:

         TimeStamp          Sensor_one   Sensor_two
    0    2017-05-20 00:00:00    1           1
    1    2017-04-13 00:00:00    1           1
    2    2017-09-10 00:00:00    0           1



    import pandas as pd

    df_Sensor = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp' : ['2017-05-25 00:00:00','2017-05-20 00:00:00', '2017-04-13 00:00:00', '2017-08-29 01:15:12', '2017-08-15 02:15:12', '2017-09-10 00:00:00'], 'Sensor_one': [1,1,1,1,1,0], 'Sensor_two': [1,1,1,0,1,1]})

    df_Message = pd.DataFrame({'date init': ['2017-05-22 00:00:00', '2017-08-14 00:00:10'], 'date end': ['2017-05-26 00:00:05', '2017-09-01 02:10:05'],  'Message': ['Cold', 'Cold']})
```

## just to illustrate the desired output:

df_Result_Sensor = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp' : ['2017-05-20 00:00:00', '2017-04-13 00:00:00', '2017-09-10 00:00:00'], 'Sensor_one': [1,1,0], 'Sensor_two': [1,1,1]})

Answer (score 0):

This will work,make sure your date columns are converted to datetime before date comparisons

```
df_Message["date init"] = pd.to_datetime(df_Message["date init"])
df_Message['date end'] = pd.to_datetime(df_Message['date end'])
df_Sensor["TimeStamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df_Sensor["TimeStamp"])

df_Sensor_  = df_Sensor.copy()
for index, row in df_Message.iterrows():
    df_Sensor_ = df_Sensor_[~((df_Sensor_["TimeStamp"] > row['date init']) & (df_Sensor_["TimeStamp"] < row['date end'])) ]

df_Result_Sensor = df_Sensor_
```